How to retrieve data from SQLite in android studio
Im currently doing a project and i make this SQLite database for the login and signup feature but i dont know how to retrieve the data to show it on textview.Please help
this is my databaseHelper class
class DatabaseHelper(private val context: Context):
        SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION){


    companion object {
        private const val DATABASE_NAME = "Userdatabase.bd"
        private const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        private const val TABLE_NAME = "data"
        private const val COLUMN_ID ="id"
        const val COLUMN_USERNAME="username"
        const val COLUMN_MSSV="mssv"
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        val createTableQuery = ("CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (" +
                "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "$COLUMN_USERNAME TEXT," +
                "$COLUMN_MSSV TEXT)")
        db?.execSQL(createTableQuery)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        val dropTableQuery = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $TABLE_NAME"
        db?.execSQL(dropTableQuery)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    fun insertUser(username: String, mssv: String): Long{
        val values = ContentValues().apply {
            put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username)
            put(COLUMN_MSSV, mssv)
        }

        val db = writableDatabase
        return db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
    }

    fun readUser(username: String, mssv: String): Boolean{
        val db = readableDatabase
        val selection = "$COLUMN_USERNAME = ? AND $COLUMN_MSSV = ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(username,mssv)
        val cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null)

        val userExists = cursor.count > 0
        cursor.close()
        return userExists

    }

    fun getUser(): Cursor {
        val db = readableDatabase
        val query = "SELECT * FROM  $TABLE_NAME"
        return db.rawQuery(query, null)
    }
}

and i want to append 2 value COLUMN_NAME and COLUMN_MSSV on 2 difference textview in MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var databaseHelper: DatabaseHelper
    private lateinit var Login: Button
    private lateinit var txtName: TextView
    private lateinit var txtMSSV: TextView
    private lateinit var insertbtn: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        insertbtn = findViewById(R.id.insertbtn)
        Login = findViewById(R.id.Login)
        LoginActivityListener()
        read()
    }


    private fun LoginActivityListener(){
        Login.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this,LoginActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun read() {
        insertbtn.setOnClickListener {
            val cursor = databaseHelper.getUser()

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                  txtName.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_USERNAME)) + "\n")
                txtMSSV.append(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COLUMN_MSSV)) + "\n")
            }
            cursor.close()
        }

    }


Currently it didn't work, it keep exit the app when i click the insert button

Post the outputs from Logcat for more details.

Is there a reason why you are not using Room?

@ih8ie8 idk about that, its my first time using SQLite so idk about it and how to use it?
